# Wireless networking on Debian

Tags: debian, networking, wifi

I've used Fedora, CentOS, Ubuntu and Arch and never been totally stuck for wireless networking.

I'm using Debian with KDE and I'm stuck.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enxa0cec804446d: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:ce:c8:04:44:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.25/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enxa0cec804446d
       valid_lft 86217sec preferred_lft 86217sec
    inet6 fe80::a2ce:c8ff:fe04:446d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I believe I installed the Broadcom driver correctly (I'm on an early 2015 MacBook Pro).

I know it's a no-no, but I have both network-manager and wicd right now out of desparation for seing a wireles network.

Results of:  `sudo modprobe wl ; ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enxa0cec804446d: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:ce:c8:04:44:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.25/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enxa0cec804446d
       valid_lft 84676sec preferred_lft 84676sec
    inet6 fe80::a2ce:c8ff:fe04:446d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: What is the output of: lspci | grep Network

Comment: broadcom-sta-dkms is the driver I installed.  I ran a command and believe it was BCM4360-2 I needed a driver for.  This link https://packages.debian.org/stretch/broadcom-sta-dkms seems to indicate it should work, even though it only lists BCM4360- .  Thanks for your response.

Comment: @arochester    03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC (rev 01)

Comment: Does a `sudo modprobe wl ; ip a` show new interfaces?

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro   It seems to be the same: Posted at end of question.

Comment: There is a Youtube video recommending these commands. It says it's for Debian/Ubuntu, but he's working on Ubuntu. Recommended?    sudo apt-get –purge remove firmware-b43-installer

sudo apt-get –purge remove dkms

sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: So I performed this, still no luck:   For devices with a BCM4301 chip or the BCM4306 revision 2 chip, install firmware-b43legacy-installer:

apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer

Answer (score 1):

### Issue at Hand

You report that your installation of Debian does not have the necessary wireless firmware to utilize WiFi on your 2015 Macbook Pro. As shown by the output of of `ip a`, your system does not recognize that there is a wireless interface at all.

### Solution

1. First, make sure you are connected to a wired network, or have access to a device with a working internet connection.
2. Next, verify that your `sources.list` includes the `non-free` repository. Here is an example if you are using Debian Stretch:

   ```
   deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
   deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
   ```

   Run `apt update` if you had to make any changes to your `sources.list`.
3. Install `wireless-tools` either via `apt` or from [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/wireless-tools). Optionally, you may want `NetworkManager` too. Once installed, verify that `iwconfig` exists by running it or using the full path: `/sbin/iwconfig`. If it detects your hardware, configure your WiFi following [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse). Since you are using KDE, you should only need to follow [the steps outlined for KDE](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#KDE_Plasma).
4. Confirm the name of your wireless device by running the following commands:

   ```
   update-pciids # if necessary; run as root, to update PCI database
   lspci | grep -E "Atheros|Broadcom"
   ```

   This will find your card, if it is Atheros or Broadcom, change the search parameter as needed. E.g. Wireless, Intel, etc.
5. If your firmware is `BCM4360-2` as you note in the comments then you will need to install `firmware-brcm80211`. You can find that [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-brcm80211) or you can install it via `apt install firmware-brcm80211`. Reboot and configure your WiFi following the [steps outlined on the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse).
6. Alternatively, or potentially in addition to the previous step, you can follow the instructions [outlined here](https://wiki.debian.org/brcmfmac).

> 1. Download the firmware from the Linux firmware git repo. (https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin)
> 2. Move this file to the folder /lib/firmware/brcm/, creating the folder if necessary.
> 3. Reboot the system.
> 4. [Configure](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse) your wireless interface as appropriate.

### Conclusion

Now you should have a working wireless connection on your 2015 Macbook Pro.

I am including a link to the [Debian Wiki on Macbook wireless](https://wiki.debian.org/MacBook/Wireless), as well as a link to [the installation guide for Debian on a early 2015 Macbook Pro](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple/MacBookPro/Early-2015-13-inch). The latter should be especially useful to you.

If needed I recommend that you backup any important data files and do a fresh install following [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple/MacBookPro/Early-2015-13-inch).

Please comment if you have any questions or issues with this answer. I highly suggest you read through each link I have provided thoroughly before attempting the commands. I appreciate feedback to correct any misconceptions and to improve my posts. I can update my answer as needed.

Best of Luck!